# Unable to trigger mail from nodejs to Alibaba Cloud Direct Mail?

Tags: alibaba-cloud

I am not able to trigger the mail using the SMTP Interface, I changed only the sample code. I have even doublechecked the password. It is correct.

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
// create reusable transporter object using SMTP transport.
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    "host": "smtpdm.aliyun.com",
   "port": 25,
  "secureConnection": false, // use SSL
  "auth": {
    "user": 'admin@mail.actestdomain.xyz', // user name
    "pass": '**CorrectPassword**'
}
});
    var mailOptions = {
    from: 'NickName<username@userdomain>', // sender address mailfrom must be same with the user.
    to: 'Admin@acclouddemo', // list of receivers
    cc:'', // copy for receivers
    bcc:'', // secret copy for receivers
    subject: 'Hello', // Subject line
    text: 'Hello world', // plaintext body
    html: '<b>Hello world</b><img class="img-responsive"src="cid:01" style="width:200px;height:auto">'

};
// send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if(error){
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
});
```

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

This possibly might be the issue with the `host` attribute in your transporter properties,

Make sure you are accessing the correct URL, as per the region,

- SMTP service address (China East 1): smtpdm.aliyun.com
- SMTP service address (Singapore): smtpdm-ap-southeast-1.aliyun.com
- SMTP service address (Sydney): smtpdm-ap-southeast-2.aliyun.com

Find below link for more details

https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/29449.htm

Comment: Let me try that.. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues in your code:

1) Make sure you are pointing the host correctly

> - SMTP service address (China East 1): smtpdm.aliyun.com
> - SMTP service address (Singapore): smtpdm-ap-southeast-1.aliyun.com
> - SMTP service address (Sydney): smtpdm-ap-southeast-2.aliyun.com

2) Configure the port

> SMTP port: 25, 80, 465 (SSL encrypted).

**Note:** Port 25 is currently disabled to maintain ECS security. If your sending application is deployed on Alibaba Cloud ECS, we recommend that you use port 80 when SSL is not checked, and use port 465 when SSL is checked.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code:

Use the correct endpoint. Unless you are actually in China and Direct Mail is configure for one of the China regions your endpoint is wrong.

You cannot use port 25. This is blocked by Alibaba. Use port 465.

You must enable secureConnection.